# Search IP Addresses in Access tables

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a database with a table that houses many fields which I've successfully created queries to search for, with the exception of IP Addresses. I have been asked, by leadership, to find a way to search by IP Address. This is a HUGE challenge for me... The IP Addresses are currently stored in Text format in the table and using an expression such as:
`Like "*" & [Forms]![FormName]![IPAddress] & "*" OR [Forms]![FormName]![IPAddress] Is Null` returns an error saying the expression is incorrect or too complicated for Access. In some of the IP Address fields, several IP's are listed, separated by a comma (Though I think I'd prefer a semicolon) and need to be able to search for all or portions of any IP in the list.

Help?

Comment: Create a function that is able to parse your recordings. Then use this in a query, or open the table as a recordset in VBA and search.

Comment: Your IP field is multivalue? or users can type several IP Addresses, separating values by commas? Also, post the code/design you have tried until now

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns users are asked to potentially list several IP's, separated by commas. Found an article that helped me sort out part of the issue; I've successfully sorted out how to search for an entire IP within a list. In the query builder, I've created 4 extra columns to parse out and sort (ascending) the individual bits of the IP, then just use a form's text box as criteria to search:

Comment: The problem I'm having now is that I get errors when I add additional criteria for other fields. Access returns the expression is too complex to evaluate.

Comment: Can you post some example data?